# Creating a multipart/form-data entity with Apache HTTP client

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, multipartform-data, contextio

I'm trying to create an HTTP entity for a POST request that looks like the one listed as part of the contextIO API listed here:

http://context.io/docs/2.0/accounts/messages#post

From their docs, they give the following example:

```
POST /2.0/accounts/4f01234567890abcdef09876/messages/ HTTP/1.1
Host: api.context.io
Accept: */*
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="abcdef1234",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_timestamp="1327695986",oauth_nonce="6dPrHNDrx5hzfHkn",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_signature="MFOyvf5Ykcsn7une48kGW0Aharw%3D"
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------someRandomBoundary
Content-Length: 1917

--------someRandomBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="dst_folder"

testFolder
--------someRandomBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="message"; filename="message.eml"
Content-Type: message/rfc822

Delivered-To: jim@bob.com
Received: by 101.42.118.54 with SMTP id hp10cs194007icb;
        Thu, 13 Jan 2012 15:02:20 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <blahblahblah@someisp.com>
Received: from [192.168.1.5] (71-211-196-225.hlrn.bob.com. [71.211.196.225])
        by mx.bob.com with ESMTPS id u41si888834ybu.20.2011.10.13.14.54.54
        (version=TLSv1/SSLv3 cipher=OTHER);
        Thu, 13 Jan 2012 15:02:20 -0700 (PDT)
Received: from mail-gx0-f174.someisp.com (mail-gx0-f174.someisp.com [109.45.123.134])
        by mx.someisp.com with ESMTPS id u41si888834ybu.20.2011.10.13.14.54.54
        (version=TLSv1/SSLv3 cipher=OTHER);
        Thu, 13 Jan 2012 14:54:53 -0700 (PDT)
Message-ID: <2E973E2A.3150305@bob.com>
Date: Thu, 13 Jan 2012 15:54:50 -0600
From: Dave Davidson <blahblahblah@someisp.com>
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.21) Gecko/20110831 Thunderbird/3.1.13
MIME-Version: 1.0
To: Jim Bob <jim@bob.com>
Subject: Just sending out a test message
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="------------030009050309030308020807"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--------------030009050309030308020807
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Yo! This is a test multi-part message.


--------------030009050309030308020807
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="#ffff00" text="#ff0000">
    Yo! This is a test multi-part message.<br>
  </body>
</html>

--------------030009050309030308020807--

--------someRandomBoundary--
```

I've tried to do this using:

```
HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                    .addBinaryBody("message", messageSource.getBytes(), ContentType.create("message/rfc822"), "message.eml")
                    .addTextBody("dst_folder", label)
                    .addTextBody("dst_source", "0")
                    .build();
```

But I can't seem to wrap the whole thing in a multipart/form-data section. **Any ideas how to create this request using the Apache HTTP Client?**

Comment: Are you trying to nest the multipart you've created inside another multipart? The answer provided by @Chloe seems to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this after:

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://api.context.io//2.0/accounts/4f01234567890abcdef09876/messages/");
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

I also see they use OAuth, and the nasty kind (1.0). Calculating an OAuth 1.0 signature is very tedious. You will find it much easier to use an OAuth library to make the requests.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @Chloe does not add the boundary= parameter to the content-type header.

You can force HTTP Client to add that parameter to Content-Type header, but it takes some hacks. This describes the process in detail - https://servicesunavailable.wordpress.com/2015/03/04/using-apache-httpclient-4-x-for-multipart-uploads-with-jersey-1-x-server/